# How to fix this warning when loading ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I am seeing the following error when ubuntu 22.04 is loading. Everything works fine, but I am just wondering how to get rid of that. I had logs set to level 3 but yet this error shows up:

> usb 1-4 Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp.
> 1)"

[image]

It sounds related to the USB but it seems the camera, mouse, and keyboard are working fine.

Comment: It's just a warning. If everything is working fine you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Yes, again... One would think the comments in your previous question were enough.

Comment: @ChanganAuto This is a different error, I modified the previous question

Comment: Yes, it is but the reasoning, causes and possible solutions are the same. The point being: If it boots and works as expected, ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux in general emits a lot of diagnostic messages while booting and after booting.  You can't "get rid" of them.  There is a nice pretty splash screen that covers them up, but you seem to have bypassed or disabled that.  If you don't want to see these messages, don't look for them!

If everything is working, there's no reason to look for or worry about these messages.  If there is a device not performing correctly, these messages might help diagnose the problem.

This particular message appears to indicate that a USB camera was accessed by software that tried to perform a function the camera doesn't support.  If the camera is working, likely the software tried several functions until it found one that is supported, and the message is completely harmless.

Comment: The camera app works for couple of seconds and then loops. This behavior happens for the default "cheese" app for camera, and it do that even before I click on capturing a photo. 

This is a fresh installation of ubuntu so I will need to test the camera with another software instead of the default one. Thanks for your explanation! If the problem persists I will investigate how to fix the camera issue.

Comment: This could be a problem with the software expecting the camera to do more than it does, and different software may be more robust.  Or it could be a bug in the kernel device driver for the camera in which case a newer kernel may have bug fixes in the driver.  You should get the exact camera model (USB device id?) and google search for that and linux and see if there is another forum discussing the camera's drivers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it : )